# understand patterns in vim

Tags: vim

I have a following file:

```
8635147+876+5597+1686+54=8643360
2415+382376+88324+81544+926+68619475+677+222852=69398589
80+21+4478882+8945092=13424075
62+9598=9660
16832904+537+51460155+6822+2+4901436+47443+5669+855928+8113549+424282=82648727
33+9872=9905
555839
5017598+5639262+4+62+9413+4+4991+41568=10712902
4977+164+77+1018643+593851+83730=1701442
220+6831+26=7077
5+54102+1034451=1088558
37844
1
35+2983325+0+6400=2989760
8081+8361365+6+477=8369929
66+68232+9406935+6489662=15964895
6569+59336692+75+11328=59354664
28332+725+2683+45913425+9648987+4911=55599063
69724687+8+7+9940+5568+29585+518916=70288711
1804642
659157+5144361+7072+16+4799+811+58742059+451875+138174=65148324
2288508+509472+43+83704=2881727
872027+1115415+1+47922+547008+56+5550+71642773+948394=75179146
142
```

I would like to sort this in `vim` to this:

```
16832904+537+51460155+6822+2+4901436+47443+5669+855928+8113549+424282=82648727
872027+1115415+1+47922+547008+56+5550+71642773+948394=75179146
69724687+8+7+9940+5568+29585+518916=70288711
2415+382376+88324+81544+926+68619475+677+222852=69398589
659157+5144361+7072+16+4799+811+58742059+451875+138174=65148324
6569+59336692+75+11328=59354664
28332+725+2683+45913425+9648987+4911=55599063
66+68232+9406935+6489662=15964895
80+21+4478882+8945092=13424075
5017598+5639262+4+62+9413+4+4991+41568=10712902
8635147+876+5597+1686+54=8643360
8081+8361365+6+477=8369929
35+2983325+0+6400=2989760
2288508+509472+43+83704=2881727
1804642
4977+164+77+1018643+593851+83730=1701442
5+54102+1034451=1088558
555839
37844
33+9872=9905
62+9598=9660
220+6831+26=7077
142
1
```

I can do it with `:sor!n/.*\</`. As I understand, `\<` means the beginning of a word. However, why doesn't simply `:sor!n/.*=/` work? Or if `=` is a special character in pattern, then I would expect that `:sor!n/.*\=/` works, but this gives a `NFA regex` error.

Comment: My eyes hurt trying to read that. In words, what sorting order are you aiming for, please?

Comment: @roaima I would like to sort numbers in descending order and on those `n+m+...= x` lines I only want to use the `x`(sum of the calculation) for sorting.

Comment: Do you definitely need to do this in the text editor, and not with other, more appropriate tools (eg. [`sort`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html))?

Comment: @JigglyNaga, `vim`'s `sort` in this instance, is functionally more powerful than the Unix `sort` command. I don't think you can do it with Unix `sort` without preprocessing the data first.

Answer (score 5):

This might be best suited to https://vi.stackexchange.com/

But anyhow, `:h :sort` actually explains what is happening in there:

```
If a {pattern} is used, any lines which don't have a
match for {pattern} are kept in their current order,
but separate from the lines which do match {pattern}.
If you sorted in reverse, they will be in reverse
order after the sorted lines, otherwise they will be
in their original order, right before the sorted
lines.
```

In simple words, `.*\<` match every line in the input and `:sort` is performed on all lines.

Whilst `.*=` matches only lines that do contain an `=`, therefore those lines are sorted by `:sort`.  All remaining lines (the ones that did not match the pattern):

```
142
1804642
1
37844
555839
```

Are not sorted, but plainly dumped at the beginning of the file.  Thanks to the fact that you're using `!` the order of all lines is reversed, so they end at the end of the file and in reverse order.

Answer (score 2):

To complement [grochmal's fine answer](/a/298774), you could use

```
:sort!n/.*=\|^/
```

Or:

```
:sort!n/[^=]*$/r
```

To get the desired result.

As to why `\=` gives you an error, is because it's a special regex operator in `vim`. It's the same as `\?` except that it can also be used in the `?` command. `.*\=` same as `.*\?` would then be an invalid regexp.